# importing numpy shows warning when running in mod_wsgi

Tags: python, numpy, mod-wsgi

I am running a Flask application in Apache using mod_wsgi. When I try to import numpy, I get the following warning:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/__init__.py:67: UserWarning: NumPy was imported from a Python sub-interpreter but NumPy does not properly support sub-interpreters. This will likely work for most users but might cause hard to track down issues or subtle bugs. A common user of the rare sub-interpreter feature is wsgi which also allows single-interpreter mode. Improvements in the case of bugs are welcome, but is not on the NumPy roadmap, and full support may require significant effort to achieve.

Should I do anything to address this warning?

Comment: As the warning said, it might cause hard to track down issues or subtle bugs. That exactly happened to me.  You can see the details in my comment to Micheael Wahler's answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Following the information [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/modwsgi/wikis/ApplicationIssues.wiki#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API), you can eliminate the warning (and prevent potential problems) by adding

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

to your httpd.conf.

Comment: Works also in the case of NumPy imported as a dependency through another package.

Comment: I'd been struggling with problems from a Django app served with Apache and mod_wsgi for days. When accessed from a browser, the app sometimes ran normally (the page got downloaded and displayed as expected), but most of times it just hang there with no errors in the Apache error log. The warning about NumPy was there from the begin, but I was not sure if that had anything to do with the problems and didn't know how to fix it (actually didn't know it could be fixed at all). Your answer fixed the problems! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Lifesaver, you saved me about 5 hours!

Comment: I have saved so much time with stackoverflow, so happy to help someone else @HaydenEastwood